# Carousel/slideshow only on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm tasked with making a carousel/slideshow of 3 images, that will only work on mobile. On desktop, those images will be displayed in 3 columns. Is there a way where it can convert automatically without me having to create two different modules and hide/display one based on the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

You should try https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ or you can add code here so i can review.